# Delete row if cell already exists

Tags: excel

I have an excel sheet that contains pets and a name.

```
Example:

column1 column2

dog     raymond
cat     raymond
spider  raymond
dog     steve
```

I only want one of each pet, so I want to delete the second instance of it, in this case steve. How can I delete the entire row if it already exists?

Answer (score 0):

Use "Remove Dupulicates" of Excel.

Following URL show instructions to use "Remove Duplicates" in Excel.

http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/remove-duplicates.html

In your case, select 'column1' only to remove duplicates of pets.